# How to make association with files in Windows 10

Tags: windows, compilation, windows-10

I have a program that is not installed in the standard sense, but is downloaded and used already installed. Accordingly, when you associate with files, Windows does not see this program. A question: how to make so that this program appeared in the settings of the default application in Windows 10?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which language is your application written in?

Comment: Its Baka Mplayer, you can look at that

Comment: It is not my job to hunt around for information you should be providing! You are a new user asking a question that is lacking a lot of details, don't expect people to spend a huge amount of time to help you. I'd recommend that you add more details before the downvotes start pouring in...

Comment: One more time, I need an answer: can I add not installed program in DEFAULT APPS in Windows 10 SETTINGS?

Comment: Yes you can but you have not even tagged the question with a programming language so how could I even begin to write sample code for you?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN tells you how you [register an Application for Use with Default Programs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx#registration). You should also read the [Guidelines for File Associations and Default Programs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872123(v=vs.85).aspx).

If your program does not have a installer then the program itself must write these registry entries.

You might also want to register your file extensions in the ["Open With" menu/dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127445(v=vs.85).aspx).